# HashSet<T>.IntersectWith() returning 0 results

Tags: c#, hashset

I am trying to grab common values between two `HashSets` of the same type with identical lists, yet I get 0 values returned after the `IntersectWith` command.  I am using the same list to begin with as a troubleshooting test, but eventually the value of `returnlist` will change as int y iterates through the sequence.

Debugging shows that `comparelist.IntersectWith(returnlist);` changes `comparelist` to 0 items.   Just to clarify, `returnlist` and `comparelist` contain the same items in the same order.

```
CfgPersonQuery firstquery = new CfgPersonQuery();
firstquery.Filter.Add("skill_dbid", skills.First());
comparelist = new HashSet<CfgPerson>(confService.RetrieveMultipleObjects<CfgPerson>(firstquery));
foreach (int y in skills.Skip(1))
{
    try
    {
        CfgPersonQuery query = new CfgPersonQuery();
        query.Filter.Add("skill_dbid", skills.First());
        HashSet<CfgPerson> returnlist = new HashSet<CfgPerson>(
            confService.RetrieveMultipleObjects<CfgPerson>(query));
        comparelist.IntersectWith(returnlist);
    }
    catch
    {                    
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us `CfgPerson` implementation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what specifically you're asking for.  How can I go about obtaining that info for you?  The CfgPerson object is part of an SDK I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not own `CfgPerson` class and you cannot implement `Equals` method you should tell `HashSet` how to determine equality for that type. You can create  `HashSet` using constructor which takes `IEqualityComparer<T>` as parameter.

So:

1) create class `CfgPersonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<CfgPerson>` (need to read documentation how to do it)
2) `var comparer = new CfgPersonEqualityComparer()`
3) `var hashSet1 = new HashSet(collection1, comparer)`
4) `var hashSet2 = new HashSet(collection2, comparer)`
5) `var result = hashSet1.IntersectWith(hashSet2)` (it will automatically detect that both HashSets use the same equality comparers)

Or just create wrapper around `CfgPerson` which implements `GetHasCode`, `Equals` and `IEquatable<CfgPerson>`.

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up building a custom IEqualityComparer for CfgPerson and it worked perfectly!